# How to remove submodule from Gitlab repository

Tags: git

I'm trying to remove a single submodule from the repository. After submodule was removed from .gitmodule I started getting an exception message `fatal: No url found for submodule path`

Output of `git status` is

```
On branch task/My-task
Your branch is up to date with origin/task/My-task
```

.gitmodules content is

```
[submodule "MySubmodule"]
    path = MySubmodule
    url = ../MySubmodule.git
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1260982/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-submodules%5D+remove

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all find submodule path with the `git submodule` command. The second step is to remove all the references to this submodule with commands called one-by-one:

1. `git submodule deinit {submodule path}`.
2. `git rm --cached {submodule path}`.
3. Remove a folder with the submodule. That's all. All that's left to do is commit the changes.
4. `git config --remove-section submodule.{submodule path}`

Ex:

1. `git submodule deinit MySubmodule`
2. `git rm --cached MySubmodule`.
3. `git config --remove-section submodule.MySubmodule`